# Moving properties in Manage User Properties

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, user-profile-service

So I have a list of properties, I need to put them all in an order that they were for the old site but I am having problems when trying to move certain properties past other ones where rather than move them past it just seems to refresh the page, has anyone experienced this?

Comment: What is the SharePoint version? what is the page name or url where you try to manage user properties?

Comment: The sharepoint version is 2016, working on a server at the moment, "_layouts/15/MgrProperty.aspx?ProfileType=User&ApplicationID" follows the server name, it seems as though I cant move properties of data type integer past datatype string?

Comment: wow, I have the same issue.

Comment: Is there any chance it could be an SP 2016 problem then? We're migrating from an older version and we've recreated all the user properties and now have to move them all into the same place they were in the old site, not only is this tedious having to use the up and down arrows but it actually makes it an impossible task when I can't move certain properties past others, I've tried a power-shell script too to no avail so far.

Comment: I have SP 2013 and have the same issue. Portal was migrated from SP2010 to 2013

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with PowerShell, since reording via UI always gets stuck with "Picture Placeholder State" property

[Article](http://www.sharepointfire.com/MyBlog/2014/02/moving-user-properties-up-in-sharepoint-with-powershell/)

First create a connection to the User Profile Manager

```
$MySite = Get-SPSite <MySiteHostURL>
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $MySite
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
```

Then type

```
$profilemanager.properties | ft name,displayorder
```

To view the current order

You can set the display order for a property using PowerShell but always make sure this ID does not exist and only use this command when you get stuck from moving a property up.

In this scenario I will move it to 5101 which is above ‘WorkEmail’

```
$profileManager.Properties.SetDisplayOrderByPropertyName("Custom",5101)
$profileManager.Properties.CommitDisplayOrder()
```